# how to check that string starts with another string in java

Tags: java

I would like to get `string` that starts with another `string` (that I should fix it) I used the following codes but I get also `string` that begins with other `string` that I wouldn't like to get!

```
 if (critere.equals("Date")) {
                    String date = jTextField5.getText();

                    try {
                        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(jTextField1.getText()));
                        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

                        //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
                        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                        //Iterate through each rows one by one
                        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                        for (Row row : sheet) {
                            for (Cell cell : row) {



                                  /* SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                                   Date d = dateFormat.parse(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                                   SimpleDateFormat printFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                                   Date dd = printFormat1.parse(printFormat1.format(d));*/

                               if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().startsWith(date)) {// I have problem here


                                    CellReference ref = new CellReference("A1");
                                    CellReference ref1 = new CellReference("B1");
                                    CellReference ref2 = new CellReference("C1");
                                    CellReference ref3 = new CellReference("D1");
                                    CellReference ref4 = new CellReference("E1");
                                    CellReference ref5 = new CellReference("G1");
                                    CellReference ref6 = new CellReference("I1");
                                    CellReference ref7 = new CellReference("J1");

                                    Cell c = row.getCell(ref.getCol());
                                    Cell c1 = row.getCell(ref1.getCol());
                                    Cell c2 = row.getCell(ref2.getCol());
                                    Cell c3 = row.getCell(ref3.getCol());
                                    Cell c4 = row.getCell(ref4.getCol());
                                    Cell c5 = row.getCell(ref5.getCol());
                                    Cell c6 = row.getCell(ref6.getCol());
                                    Cell c7 = row.getCell(ref7.getCol());





                                    if (c.getStringCellValue().equals("Warning")) {

                                        ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).addRow(new Object[]{c.getStringCellValue(), c1.getStringCellValue(), c2.getStringCellValue(),
                                            c3.getStringCellValue(), c4.getStringCellValue(), c5.getStringCellValue(), c6.getStringCellValue(), c7.getStringCellValue()});
                                    }
                                    if (c.getStringCellValue().equals("Minor")) {

                                        ((DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel()).addRow(new Object[]{c.getStringCellValue(), c1.getStringCellValue(), c2.getStringCellValue(),
                                            c3.getStringCellValue(), c4.getStringCellValue(), c5.getStringCellValue(), c6.getStringCellValue(), c7.getStringCellValue()});
                                    }
                                    if (c.getStringCellValue().equals("Major")) {

                                        ((DefaultTableModel) jTable3.getModel()).addRow(new Object[]{c.getStringCellValue(), c1.getStringCellValue(), c2.getStringCellValue(),
                                            c3.getStringCellValue(), c4.getStringCellValue(), c5.getStringCellValue(), c6.getStringCellValue(), c7.getStringCellValue()});
                                    }
                                    if (c.getStringCellValue().equals("Critical")) {

                                        ((DefaultTableModel) jTable4.getModel()).addRow(new Object[]{c.getStringCellValue(), c1.getStringCellValue(), c2.getStringCellValue(),
                                            c3.getStringCellValue(), c4.getStringCellValue(), c5.getStringCellValue(), c6.getStringCellValue(), c7.getStringCellValue()});
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

I would like to enter this loop when the date starts with a date that I should enter in my application as input but when I run my app it enter to this loop even the date didn't start with the value that I did enter

Comment: Unclear what you are saying. Can you give example?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem. We don't know what `getString()` returns, or what `date` is.

Answer (score 2):

See this example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_startswith.htm

Maybe your data variable is not a String?

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      String str = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");

      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(str.startsWith("Welcome") );

      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(str.startsWith("Tutorials") );

      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(str.startsWith("Tutorials", 11) );
   }
}
```

This produces the following result:

> Return Value :true
>
> Return Value :false
>
> Return Value :true

Comment: OK. Corrected.. I just copy it and paste as mentioned. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I presume the `date` is a `String` variable so you need to check if it is a subString of the whole and if the index of its first occurrence is 0

If `date` is not a `String` first transform it into one

```
if(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().indexOf(date.toString()) == 0);
```

Comment: What’s the supposed benefit of using `.indexOf(date) == 0` instead of `.startsWith(date)`?

Comment: it is just another form of the same thing(although i know that `startsWith()` is preferred if posible)

Comment: So why do think, doing “the same thing” in “just another form” will help solving the OP’s problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem I have an other colnum that starts with the string date in the same row so that 's why when I run the code it take also strings that starts with date in the other colnum